# Gmail inbox- preview last email, not first, in conversation

Tags: gmail

In the gmail inbox, the conversations show a preview that contains the beginning of the first email in the conversation. Is there a way to change the preview to show the beginning of the *last* email in the conversation instead?

Comment: ... it does... This might be caused by inconsistent timestamps between messages and replies.

Comment: I googled this and it seems like it was an bug that gmail was aware of. Today it is fixed :).

Answer (score 2):

Can you add a screen shot? Because in both my personal Gmail account and work (Google Apps mail) account, the single line preview for a conversation is the beginning of the last (most recent) message in the convo.

Oh, and i believe Google calls these "Snippets".

**Edit:**

[This might be related](http://groups.google.com/group/gmail-users/browse_thread/thread/3080ac3e33cb8ab8?pli=1) to [Priority Inbox](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/priority-inbox.html). Do you have that turned on? ([you can turn it off](http://www.callingallgeeks.org/how-to-disable-gmail-priority-inbox/))